# HTML5 working with wrong doctype on some browsers only

Tags: android, html, css

Because everyone is talking about HTML5 I decided to create a website using HTML5 yesterday. On Chrome and Desktop PC is looks fine on notebooks and netbooks too but then I tested on a Samsung S4 and got a very bad looking website using Chrome and then Opera (both for Android)
Then I changed the doctype from HTML5 to 4.1 strict but nothing more and uploaded a copy of the same website and it started to look good again on Chrome and 1 opera version (not the new mini)

Questions:

How can it be possible that a website using HTML5 is not recognized by some browsers with it's doctype but changing to older doctype it works fine?

What do you recommend for doctype in this case so I have multi browser compatibility because HTML5 is not really 100% ready for all browsers...

Last but not least: You remember I wrote about yesterday my website was looking bad because of the doctype, well today the same page with the HTML doctype is working fine on Chrome for android again? So yesterday it did not and now it does?

Can it be cache from the copy I uploaded but using 4.1 strict doctype?

Here is the doctype I have right now

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Html 4.x was based on SMGL (http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language)
HTML 5 does not need DTD ( Document Type Definition) so you can just use that simple tag to define how browsers should render your website.
You are correct that not all browsers interp HTML5 100%, but it is more then enough supported to just say that your page is HTML5.

On your first question: I would need examples. Although I might can understand that the browser does not really 'understands' the 'old' doctype and just sort of ignores it and sees it as HTML5. See my above text which MIGHT have to do with it.

Your last question; yes this could very be a cached copy!